# What is the cost of buying scrolls in Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

A recent Adventurers League (AL) adventure has a vendor who sells 1st to 3rd level scrolls to adventurers.

(Spoiler)

> The vendor Wakanga in the adventure Tomb of Annihilation

What are the AL costs for these scrolls?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey There seems to be some confusion across various forums what the costs might actually be. We only saw homebrew prices suggested so we are looking for AL legal prices

Answer (score 8):

Wakanga's costs for his items in that adventure appear to be listed on p. 27 of

> *Tomb of Annihilation*.

1st-level spell scrolls are listed at 100 gp. 2nd-level spell scrolls are listed as being 550 gp. No third-level scrolls are listed, though he seems to have potions of common and uncommon rarity as well.